# One of my bakers has been hacked. Any negative impacts on delegators?

Tags: baker

One of the bakers that I had delegated my XTZs for baking was hacked recently and has stopped its operation.  Subsequently, I have changed my baker for the affected XTZs.  I have all my XTZs in my Nano S ledger and I use TezBox and Galleon (the baker hacked was delegated via my TezBox).  I would be grateful if anyone could kindly tell me if there were anything that I should be concerned about with the regard to the hacked baker in question or/and my XTZ previously delegated to the said baker?  Many thanks in anticipation.

Kind regards

Answer (score 6):

The is no negative impact on delegators tokens when a baker gets hacked.

When you delegate your tokens in Tezos they are not locked up and they remain in your custody and control. **Note that this assumes you have control of your tokens in the first place; if you keep your tokens on an exchange then you aren't in custody and all your assets on the exchange are at risk.**

If the baker you delegated to does not pay out rewards to you as you expect because they get hacked or otherwise it is up to you to make the decision to change your delegation to a different baker. But delegating your tokens never puts your existing tokens at risk.